# How to find duplicate values in next lines?

Tags: python

I open a text file and loop on all the lines sorting each into a personally accustomed dictionary.

```
def load(fileName):
    file = open(fileName+'.txt')
    for line in file:
        row = line.split()
        id = int(row[0])
        number = int(row[2])
        values = [int(row[3]),int(row[4]),int(row[5]),int(row[6])]
        dict = {number:[id, values]}
        print(dict)
```

I want to check if a next line has duplicate values of `number` and `id` and then group and sort according to that.

I am sure a good solution would be putting all of the dictionaries into one list and then manipulating it in certain ways but i can't seem to make it work it just puts each `dict` in different a list.

How can i check for duplicates in every `line` using something similar to `.nextLine()` or an `index=0` that increments with each iteration of `line in file`?

Input example:

```
1772 320 548 340 303 20 37 1
1772 320 551 337 306 22 37 1
1772 320 551 337 306 22 37 1
1772 320 551 337 306 22 37 1
1772 320 552 336 307 22 37 1
1772 320 553 335 308 22 37 1
1772 320 554 335 309 20 37 1
1783 345 438 31 436 40 36 1
1783 345 439 33 434 40 36 1
1783 345 440 35 432 40 36 1
1783 345 441 38 430 40 36 1
1783 345 442 39 431 40 36 1
1783 345 443 41 429 40 36 1
1783 345 444 44 428 40 36 1
```

Output example:

```
{548: [1772, [340, 303, 20, 37]]}
{551: [1772, [337, 306, 22, 37]]}
{551: [1772, [337, 306, 22, 37]]}
{551: [1772, [337, 306, 22, 37]]}
{552: [1772, [336, 307, 22, 37]]}
{553: [1772, [335, 308, 22, 37]]}
{554: [1772, [335, 309, 20, 37]]}
{438: [1783, [31, 436, 40, 36]]}
{439: [1783, [33, 434, 40, 36]]}
{440: [1783, [35, 432, 40, 36]]}
{441: [1783, [38, 430, 40, 36]]}
{442: [1783, [39, 431, 40, 36]]}
{443: [1783, [41, 429, 40, 36]]}
{444: [1783, [44, 428, 40, 36]]}
```

Comment: Please give a sample input/output to make it more clear.

Comment: Please add the sample/input output in the question body not comments.

Comment: @Ashwini Chaudhary I did but i'm sad that you removed your answer

Comment: Just one line? that's doesn't help at all. Please add a better example, may be 7-8 lines with repeated as well as unique lines(similar to what you mentioned in your question).
I can undelete my answer any time, but I am not sure if that was a correct answer.

Comment: @Ashwini Chaudhary Added input output examples. Note that the changes in the values might be more frequent sometimes.

Comment: I've updated my solution, please check if that's what you wanted.

Comment: @Ashwini Chaudhary yes the only thing that i'm trying to figure out now is how to make all of the numbers with the same id appear one after the other untill no more numbers with the same id exist, then jump to a new id and display all numbers for it etc... I should have probably mentioned that different ids can have the same number...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from collections import OrderedDict as od
with open("abc") as f:
   dic = od()
   for line in f:
       row  = map(int,line.split())
       idx, num  = row[2], row[0]
       val = [num] + [row[3:-1]]
       dic.setdefault(idx,[]).append(val)

for k,v in dic.items():
    for val in v:
        print k,val
```

**output:**

```
548 [1772, [340, 303, 20, 37]]
551 [1772, [337, 306, 22, 37]]
551 [1772, [337, 306, 22, 37]]
551 [1772, [337, 306, 22, 37]]
552 [1772, [336, 307, 22, 37]]
553 [1772, [335, 308, 22, 37]]
554 [1772, [335, 309, 20, 37]]
438 [1783, [31, 436, 40, 36]]
439 [1783, [33, 434, 40, 36]]
440 [1783, [35, 432, 40, 36]]
441 [1783, [38, 430, 40, 36]]
442 [1783, [39, 431, 40, 36]]
443 [1783, [41, 429, 40, 36]]
444 [1783, [44, 428, 40, 36]]
```

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP wants at all. He didn't mention that the file is sorted by lists or numbers. The same number could appear 5 rows apart.

Comment: @Eli I did say "I want to check if a next line has duplicate values of number and id and then group and sort according to that" But i guess i should have been more clear... the key should increment as long as the same id is maintained, then a new id takes over and number starts a new incrementation

Answer (score 2):

Just keep the numbers and ids you've seen in a dictionary you append to as you go along. Since both must match, you can group them as a tuple:

```
def load(fileName):
    dupes_dic = {}
    file = open(fileName+'.txt')
    for line in file:
        row = line.split()
        id = int(row[0])
        number = int(row[2])
        values = [int(row[3]),int(row[4]),int(row[5]),int(row[6])]
        dic = {number:[id, values]}
        if dupes_dic[(number,id)]:
            #do some grouping or sorting or whatever
        else:
            dupes_dic[(number,id)] = values
```

I can add more to the answer if you explain what you want a bit more.

**EDIT:** OP actually wants items with the same number ordered by ID. In that case this should work:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
def load(fileName):
    dupes_dic = {}
    file = open(fileName+'.txt')
    for line in file:
        row = line.split()
        id = int(row[0])
        number = int(row[2])
        values = [int(row[3]),int(row[4]),int(row[5]),int(row[6])]
        if number in dupes_dic:
            dupes_dic[number][id] = values
        else:
            dupes_dic[number] = {id: values}
    for number in dupes_dic:
        dupes_dic[number]['index'] = sorted(dupes_dic[number].keys())
```

Then you just use each number's index to pull that number's ids/values in order, like:

```
def getOrderedIds(number_dic):
    for id, values in number_dic['index'].iterkeys():
        print id
        print values
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I want to group all of the lines that have the same number incrementally in relation to the id but maintain the values' original structure which is an array of integers i believe. So i don't think a tuple would be the best choice here. I'm more than likely wrong though...

Comment: The line if dupes_dic[number] == True:  Gives me an error KeyError: 1

Comment: @MaxPower Sorry, should have been: "if number in dupes_dic." The whole thing is untested so there might be another typo in there somewhere. Basic idea is the point.

Answer (score 1):

```
d = dict()
with open ("input") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip(" \n")
        row = line.split()
        if len(row) < 7: continue
        idx = int(row[0])
        number = int(row[2])
        values = [int(row[3]),int(row[4]),int(row[5]),int(row[6])]
        key = str(number) + ":" + str(idx)

        # add values corresponding to same number, idx pairs to ...
        # a list referenced by d[number:idx]

        if key not in d: d[key] = []
        d[key].append(values)

for key in d:
    n,i = key.split(":")
    # print out rows with number n and idx i
    for row in d[key]:
        print n, i, ",".join(str(x) for x in row)
```

Output:

```
551 1772 337,306,22,37
551 1772 337,306,22,37
551 1772 337,306,22,37
553 1772 335,308,22,37
552 1772 336,307,22,37
548 1772 340,303,20,37
554 1772 335,309,20,37
```